# How can I cleanly deploy RSpec & Cucumber HTML results with my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capistrano, bdd

I work with less technical stakeholders and testers on producing a Rails 3.1 app who benefit greatly from seeing the HTML output rendered by my Cucumber and RSpec tests.

I would like a way to bundle this output with the app when I deploy, but am struggling to find the cleanest way to do this. The repo is on Github and we deploy with Capistrano. I would strongly prefer keep this out of version control.

Is anyone else doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the obvious solution didn't occur to me earlier: gitignore the doc files and add a deployment task to scp the files directly into the app's public directory.

**.gitignore**

```
public/doc
```

**lib/tasks/doc.rake**

```
namespace :doc do

  desc "run features and specs then generate pages accessible in public/doc"
  task :html do
    # Delete old files
    puts "Clearing out old html files..."
    system("rm -rf public/doc/")
    system("mkdir public/doc/")

    # Generate the feature html files
    puts "Generating Cucumber html files..."
    system("mkdir public/doc/features")
    Dir.glob("features/**/*.feature").each do |story|
      system("bundle exec cucumber #{story} --drb --format=html -o public/doc/#{story.gsub(/(\w*).feature/, '\1.html')}")
      puts "public/doc/#{story}"
    end

    # Generate RSpec html files
    puts "Generating RSpec html files..."
    system("mkdir public/doc/spec/")
    Dir.glob("spec/**/*_spec.rb").each do |spec|
      system("bundle exec rspec #{spec} --drb --format html -o public/doc/#{spec.gsub(/(\w*).rb/, '\1.html')}")
    end

    # Generate the index file
    puts "Writing index file..."
    system("echo \"<html><head><title>Doc</title></head><body>\" > public/doc/index.html")

    # Write test report navigation
    Dir.glob("public/doc/**/*.html").each do |file|
      unless file == 'public/doc/index.html'
        file.gsub!(/\public\/doc\//, '')
        system("echo \"<p><a href='#{file}'>#{file.gsub('.html', '')}</a></p>\" >> public/doc/index.html")
      end
    end

    # Close index.html file
    system("echo \"</body></html>\" >> public/doc/index.html")
    puts "Done!"
  end
end
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
desc "Generate Cucumber & RSpec HTML docs"
task :generate_docs, :roles => :app do
  system("bundle exec rake doc:html")
end

desc "Copy Cucumber & RSpec HTML docs outside of version control with scp"
task :copy_docs, :roles => :app do
  system("tar -zcvf tmp/doc.tar.gz public/doc && rm -rf public/doc")
  system("scp -r -i ~/myKey.pem tmp/doc.tar.gz #{user}@#{hostname}:#{deploy_to}/current/public/doc.tar.gz && rm tmp/doc.tar.gz")
  run "cd #{release_path}; tar -zxvf public/doc.tar.gz && rm public/doc.tar.gz"
end

after 'deploy', 'docs:generate_docs', 'docs:copy_docs'
```

Answer (score 0):

the cukes are a bit easier... add a rake task:

```
desc "runs cucumber features and outputs them to doc/cucumber as html"
task :html do 
  Dir.glob("features/*.feature").each do |story|
    system("cucumber", 
           "#{story}", 
           "--format=html", 
           "-o", 
           "doc/cucumber/#{story.gsub(/features\/(\w*).feature/, '\1.html')}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion! I should have mentioned I already had a rake task similar to yours... the main part I wasn't getting was how to keep it clean and out of source control. My answer below is what I decided on, to leverage gitignore, scp and capistrano